# JQuery email validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm new to JQuery and wrote a simple validation to check the email address. But it is not working as expected. Can someone suggest to fix this?

```
<script>
   $( "#email" ).blur(function() {  
var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;  
if($( "#Email" ).val().match(mailformat))  
{  
alert("You have entered an valid email address!");   
}  
else  
{  
alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");    
}  
});
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<label for="email" id="email-ariaLabel">Your email address:</label>
 <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="required" title="This is a required field" /> <span class="msg error">Not a valid email address</span>
 <span class="msg success">A valid email address!</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will run before the elements are created, so the handler won't be attached.  You should wrap your code in `$(document).ready()` so that the code runs after the elements are created.

Also, selectors are case sensitive you should use `$("#email").val()` instead of `$("#Email").val()`

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $( "#email" ).blur(function() {  
   var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;  
   if($("#email").val().match(mailformat))  
   {  
     alert("You have entered an valid email address!");   
   }  
   else  
   {  
     alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");    
   } 
  });
})
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
<script>
   $( "#email" ).blur(function() {  
var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;  
if($( "#email" ).val().match(mailformat))  
{  
   alert("You have entered an valid email address!");   
}  
else  
{  
   alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");    
}  
});
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<label for="email" id="email-ariaLabel">Your email address:</label>
 <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="required" title="This is a required field" /> <span class="msg error">Not a valid email address</span>
 <span class="msg success">A valid email address!</span>
```

or you can simply use data annotation for `email` as

```
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Email can accept maximum 100 characters.")]
[RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\\.)+(?:[a-zA-Z]{2}|aero|asia|biz|cat|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|mobi|museum|name|net|org|pro|tel|travel)$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid email address.")]
public string email { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the code below it will solve Ur problem.

```
 <script>
       $( "#email" ).blur(function() {  
         var mailformat = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
         var emailTextField = $( "#email" ).val();
         if(!emailReg.test(emailTextField) || emailTextField.length == 0)  
         { 
           alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");
         }  
         else  
         {  
           alert("You have entered an valid email address!");
         }  
       });
    </script>
```